# Why does blender select random faces in edit mode? (Ubuntu)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]I am following this tutorial to model a basic human male https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9l9Eq4eX-I 
every time I try to select a face in edit mode it selects a different face either three faces away or on the other side of my mesh it’s becoming very tiresome and I was wondering if anyone else has had the same problem or if you know how to fix it.
Please help as I enjoy using blender but cant do much more than simple texture editing.

I click the face that has the 3D cursor by it but it selects a different one.

Comment: Please add some screenshots or a screencast of this happening.

Comment: screenshot has been added

Comment: as i know this happend in some older versions. Considder to update to the newest 2.71 version fom http://www.blender.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode, you see the three boxes for either putting select mode into 'vertex', 'edge', or 'face'?  Next to that is a button called 'Limit selection to visible'.
When it is 'selected' or darker, selecting parts of the mesh will no longer select what is behind the cursor on the other side.

See pic.

[image]

Comment: I thought of that too, but notice his screenshot, the button is off. I find this pretty weird since I haven't encountered that problem. The problem might be in the mouse.