# Selecting vertices in solid mode selects random vertices?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

I've been having this issue since I started using Blender, but just kind of went along with it. Now its becoming a genuine issue though. Whenever I select vertices in Blender (Box select, Lasso, C, etc) While viewing the object in Solid mode, Blender also selects other random vertices.
I'm using 2.78. I do not feel a blend file would help as this problem has been reoccuring every time I use blender; it's not isolated to a specific file.

[image]

This issue does not occur when selecting vertices in wireframe mode;

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? eg. blender version
Maybe a blendfile for testing purposes?

Comment: This is neither a normal behaviour nor any feature and Proportional Editing shouldn't affect *selecting*. These seem to be related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15107/why-does-blender-select-random-faces-in-edit-mode-ubuntu and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49456/random-vertices-getting-selected. More than likely this is a bug.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @bubakazouba I had to format my computer to get it working again. My guess is it is some kind of bug that exists outside of the blender software, because re-installing blender did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

1. Go to **'user preferences'**
2. Under **'system'** search for Window Draw Method
3. Change it to **'No Multisample'**
   (this disables the antialias in the 3D view).

[image]

Comment: It's already set to that. Thanks though.

Comment: One last thing... if 'Window Draw Method' is set to 'No Multisample', try setting it to a different value. Just might work, stating the obvious :)
That's about all I can think off.

Answer (score -1):

This is the result of enabling the proportional falloff tool.

If you disable it the problem should be solved.

My guess is you accidentally pressed the shortcut **'O'**
[image]

Comment: Disabling it does not change the results. It still selects random vertices.

Comment: Is the problem occurring on that specific  model or is it an issue to the whole blendfile?

Comment: It's not a specific Blend or object, It's happened with every time I've used Blender Since I got it (~A year ago)

Comment: Yes, I have tried. Have you tested if this problem occurs on your computer as well by any chance? This could just be an odd feature in Blender..