# Unexpected Selection Behavior- Selecting Random Faces of a Sphere

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

No experience in 3d modeling what-so-ever. Trying to make a pill object. Doing this by creating a sphere, cutting off the bottom, duplicating/rotating, and connecting it to a cylinder.

I've aligned my view to the object- `NUMPAD .` + `NUMPAD 1`.

Went into *Edit Mode* and selected *Faces*.

Used *Bounding Box Selection* (`B`) to select the bottom half of the sphere.

Got some unexpected results.

[image: selecting bottom half of sphere. selects visible bottom half and a dozen random faces above my select around the entire sphere]

I can imagine why it would only select the visible side of the sphere, so I need to find a way to select *through* the sphere. But why would it select random faces above my selection?

Edit:

Using *Wireframe* does fix this.

Comment: Seems to be similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68950/selecting-vertices-in-solid-mode-selects-random-vertices. Selecting half of sphere in Solid shading mode, considering Limit Selection to Visible is On, is normal behaviour. Selecting any faces not under the bounding box is not normal. Make sure to update Blender to the newest version from official site, this looks like a bug